# Сумма четных чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно посчитать сумму четных чисел Фибоначчи, которые не превышают 4 миллиона.
Увидел закономерность, что начиная с числа 2(первого парного числа Фибоначчи) парным является каждое 3 число. **2** *3 5* **8** *13 21* **34** и т.д.
Сделал такое решение, но интересно, есть ли еще более быстрое и красивое решение?

```
import math
def fib(number): 
    fn=0
    phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2
    fn = (1 / math.sqrt(5)) * (phi**number - (math.cos(math.pi * number)) / phi**number)
    print(math.trunc(fn)),
    return math.trunc(fn)

currentFib = 0
i=1
sum=0

while currentFib<4*10**6:
    currentFib = fib(i*3)
    i+=1
    sum+=currentFib
print("\n" + str(sum))
```

Comment: phi и часть fn можно рассчитать заранее

Comment: у тебя кстати ошибка... проверка на выход из цикла должна быть после вычисления очередного числа...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, действительно, спасибо. У себя починил)

Comment: [Здесь](https://oeis.org/A014445) ещё больше формул.

Comment: Поскольку вам нужен перебор чисел, а не одно конкретное число - думаю, что суммирование будет не хуже плавающей точки и возведений в степень... Но лучше вообще без вычисления ряда - так как сумма F[3*i] от 1 до n равна (F[3*n + 2] - 1)/2.

Answer (score 5):

т.к. ответ задачи не зависит ни от каких входных параметров, то самым быстрым способом будет:

```
print(4613732)
```

---

В случае если обобщать задачу на «найти сумму чётных чисел Фибоначчи, которые не превышают `N`» то можно сделать как-то так:

```
from math import log, sqrt, trunc

def sum_phib_even(N):
  if (N<8): 
    return 2 
  phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2

  n = trunc( log(N*sqrt(5), phi) )
  if (n%3 == 2 and fib(n+1) <= N):
    n = n+1
  n //= 3
  return (fib(n*3+2) - 1) / 2
```

---

#### Объяснения/обоснования

Для малых N результат может быть некорректен, поэтому сразу отметаем этот случай:

```
  if (N<8): return 2
```

Найти `n` для числа *F<sub>n</sub> ≤ N* можно так:

```
n = trunc( log(N*sqrt(5), phi) )
```

Но если `N` само является числом Фибоначчи (в частности чётным), то эта проверка может вернуть `n` на единицу меньше, поэтому нужна дополнительная проверка:

```
  if (n%3 == 2 && fib(n+1) <= N):
    n = n+1
```

Чётные числа Фибоначчи имеют вид *F<sub>3n</sub>*, поэтому:

```
n //= 3;
```

Далее, из того что

- *Σ(F<sub>n</sub>) = F<sub>n+2</sub> - 1*

не сложно вывести, что

- *Σ(F<sub>3n</sub>) = (F<sub>3n+2</sub> - 1) / 2*

, т.е. итоговая сумма вычисляется как:

```
(fib(n*3+2)-1)/2;
```

---

#### Замечания

- т.к. всё это использует арифметику с плавающей точкой, то всё это будет работать пока хватает точности мантисы т.е. примерно для чисел до 2^50.
- Большое количество арифметики с плавающей точкой при вычислении определённого числа Фибоначчи по обобщённой версии формулы Бине  — тоже довольно тяжёлая штука, так что на практике его имеет смысл заменить чем-то динамическим.

Answer (score 0):

Если понаблюдать за последовательностью, можно попробовать изобразить нечто такое:

```
def solve(N):
    sum_ = 0
    even, next_ = 0, 1

    while even <= N:
        sum_ += even
        next_, even = (
            3 * next_ + 2 * even,
            2 * next_ + even,
        )

    return sum_
```

Или даже так:

```
def solve2(N):
    sum_ = 0 
    a, b = 0, 2

    while b <= N:
        sum_ += b
        a, b = b, a+4*b

    return sum_
```

> ```
> assert solve(4e6) == 4613732
> assert solve2(4e6) == 4613732
> ```